# How to filter Reports result from Docusign Rest API in Postman

Tags: postman, docusignapi

I want to download the result of one on my custom reports so I've configured Docusign Rest API in Postman and I use the Account--> reports/report_results method to obtain the data.

After configuring the body with the ID and the customID, I see that the data of the report is there but as I have a lot of data, I want to filter it by the date. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint is not a public endpoint. Meaning, it was exposed by mistake in a prior swagger file, but now is hidden.
You cannot use this endpoint of the eSignature API as it will soon be completely removed (part of a deprecation process).

Comment: And what can I use to get the result of the reports?